# Angular 5 Confirmation Dialog Setup With Material MatDialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This setup shows success but it isn't deleting an item from the Postgres DB.  The service works when not using the confirm setup so it isn't the problem.  The confirm setup sends the correct memberId to the service but my code is failing silently, no errors, only success results without real success.  (See console.log comments.)  I suspect that .subscribe is in the wrong place but haven't found a place it works.  It does not work if directly under

```
this.membersAdminService.deleteMember(memberId)
```

This is the service which works fine:

```
  public deleteMember(memberId):  Observable<any> {
    console.log('delete called', memberId);  // 12 or correct id with both examples below.
    return this.http
      .delete(this.baseUrl + '?ids=' + memberId, {headers: this.headers});
  }
```

This component works and deletes a member:

```
public deleteMember(memberId) {
    this.membersAdminService.deleteMember(memberId)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.success();
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err.error);
          console.log(err.message);
          this.handleError(err);
        }
      );
}
```

This code doesn't delete but says it does after accepting the confirm delete option in the dialog.  It sends the correct memberId to the service but the service does nothing with it.

```
public deleteMember(memberId) {
      // Call the confirm dialog component
      this.confirmService.confirm('Confirm Delete', 'This action is final. Gone forever!')
          .do(res => {if (res === true) {
                console.log('confirm res', res);  // true
                console.log('confirm member_id', memberId);  // 12
              this.membersAdminService.deleteMember(memberId);
          }})
          .subscribe(
              result => {
                console.log('success res: ', result); // true
                this.success();  // Success modal pops up.
              },
              (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                  console.log(err.error);  // nothing
                  console.log(err.message);  // nothing
                this.messagesService.openDialog('Error', 'Delete did not happen.');
              }
          );
}
```

Any ideas?  The backend is on my computer so I don't think I can do a Plunker.

The confirm service:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { ConfirmComponent } from './confirm.component';

@Injectable()
export class ConfirmService {

  private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmComponent>;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  public confirm(title: string, message: string): Observable<any> {
      console.log('confirmed called');
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmComponent);
    this.dialogRef.componentInstance.title = title;
    this.dialogRef.componentInstance.message = message;

    return this.dialogRef.afterClosed();

  }
}
```

Comment: What does the code for this.confirmService.confirm() look like?

Comment: Added that code Marcel.  It seems to work well.  After the confirmation is accepted the component code sends the memberId to the MembersAdminService for deletion, as I expect.  After that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in the version that works, the Subscribe "pulls" the delete operation along (remember that RxJS is lazy, not eager), whereas in the example that doesn't work, you're inside that .do() and it's not pulling its weight so to speak. Try flatMap() or switchMap() (I can never remember which is which off the top of my head) instead of .do() and see if that works.

Comment: switchMap did it!  I had to add a return:      .switchMap(res => {if (res === true) {
              return this.membersAdminService.deleteMember(memberId);

Comment: For some reason I thought all RxJS operators created a new observable.  .do doesn't so nothing to drop into .subscribe with.  Thanks!